# Constraining horizontally/vertically in custom table view cell issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

This is driving me crazy. It doesn't happen every time but when it does it is annoying.

When creating a new View Controller and adding a table view, table view cell, this weird bug(?) happens when I try to add horizontal and vertical centering constraints. It pushes whatever object I am trying to constraint to the far left, and sometimes outside of the content view.

I made a gif of the issue here: [constraint issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7wTs.gif)

Am I doing something wrong or do other people experience this as well?

Comment: one of **so many** issues where IB and constraints just don't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use xib nib To Create Table View Cell. And Attach Nib To Your Table View. Then It's Works Fine.

1. --> Create New File And Select Cocoa Touch Class Then After

   2. --> Click on Drop Down To Select Table View Cell instead of default
      Selection ViewController.
   3. --> The Create UITableViewCell with
      Checking Checkbox ADD NIB Under the Drop Down(Don't Forgot to Check 
      that Check Box).
   4. --> Then You Can Get Table View Cell Nib file
      and    Class file.
   5. -->Place Reference Identifier in Nib File.
   6. -->    Register Table View Cell to Your Table View.

yourTable.register(UINib(NibName,Bundle: nil),reference: Reference Identifier)